# Front End Wobble At Low Speeds

Tags: honda, vibration, crv, frontend

I have this low speed wobble that's been driving me nuts, and I can't find anything on the internet that's similar to this. What happens, when accelerating from a stop at about 5 to 15 MPH, my front end wobbles. It's not felt in the steering wheel, and it completely goes away above 15 MPH.

And for a little more background: in the last year, I've personally replaced both front CV axles, lower ball joints and both tie rod ends. When I bought the car, it had a fairly new passenger side front strut, and I replaced the driver side strut early spring. And after all of this, the car was aligned. I've checked for play in both front wheels to see if it was bad wheel bearings, but the wheels have no play in them.

Anyway, I thought I'd ask the internet before going to the mechanic. Also, if it matters, the vehicle is a Honda CR-V with the real-time AWD.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure it's the front end which is wobbling? If you're not feeling it through the steering wheel, I'd suspect the back end is where the issue may be.

Comment: I was also reading that it could be transmission shudder. It definitely happens in the front and always at 5 to 15 MPH. ALSO, it doesn't occur consistently. Which leads me to believe that it could be transmission shudder, especially since the transmission fluid is getting pretty dark. Before I get a transmission fluid change, I'm gonna try one of those fluid additives that supposedly help stop the torque converter from slipping.